# How do I use the rand crate without the standard library?

Tags: random, rust, embedded

I'm doing embedded game development for the Sega Megadrive with Rust and would like a random number generator to increase replayability. It can be pseudo-random: there's no security stuff required.

I've been looking at the rand crate which falls in the "No standard library" department, but I'm not sure on how to use it with this in my Crate.toml:

```
[dependencies]
rand = {version = "0.8.3", default-features = false}
```

When I disable `default-features`, there's no `random` function in the prelude anymore. There is the `Rng` trait but I'm too inexperienced to figure out how to use it.

Comment: Putting that code in a file called `Crate.toml` will have no effect as nothing care about that file. Perhaps there's a simple typo to fix your problem?

Comment: Generally, random number generators need a source of entropy — what will that be on your device?

Comment: I always used [fastrand](https://crates.io/crates/fastrand), I'm not sure if it works on SEGA though

Comment: SmallRNG from the rand crate seems to work without `std`. [Here's the documentation](https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.3/rand/rngs/struct.SmallRng.html)

Comment: @Misty SmallRNG is no_std. With a date or anything at seed, it should be OK for OP's stated needs. This looks like a valid answer (only need an example)

Comment: @Misty thanks for the pointers. Looks like fastrand uses stdlib, by the looks of https://github.com/smol-rs/fastrand/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L73. SmallRNG looks promising but an example of how to use this on a no_std crate would be very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the `rand` crate without `std` you need to manually use one of the generators that work without it. Those generators are the `OsRng` and the `SmallRng` structs. As the name suggests the first one uses the operating system's generator, which requires the `getrandom` crate, which probably isn't supported on SEGA Megadrive.

`SmallRng` should work without problems though. We cannot use the `random()` function, we need to manually create the generator and then call its methods.

To do this we first have to create a generator, like this:

```
let mut small_rng = SmallRng::seed_from_u64([insert your seed here]);
```

You can also use the `seed_from_u32`, [whose documentation you can find here](https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.3/rand/rngs/struct.SmallRng.html).

Then we can use it as such:

```
let rand_num = small_rng.next_u64();
```

Importantly, we have to import the `RngCore` trait to use these functions, this way:

```
use rand::{Rng, SeedableRng};
use rand::rngs::SmallRng;
use rand::RngCore;
```

`SmallRng` relies on the `small_rng` crate feature, so you should import it this way (in the `Cargo.toml` file):

```
rand = { version = "0.8.3", features = ["small_rng"], default-features = false }
```

I should also leave a disclaimer: `SmallRng`'s generator isn't cryptographically secure.

Comment: This looks like it's getting close! The compiler now complains that it cannot compile libc:

Comment: ```
1628 | ...                   speed: ::speed_t) -> ::c_int;
     |                                ^^^^^^^ not found in the crate root
error: aborting due to 380 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0412, E0573.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0412`.
error: could not compile `libc`
```
libc is listed as an optional dependency, but it looks like small_rng requires it... Is there an obvious solution to this?

Comment: By the way I found no references to a `seed_from_u32` method... But it might not matter.

Comment: @Rein Try explicitly listing libc as a dependency. And make sure it’s listed as a required dependency

Comment: I added: `libc = { version = "0.2.94", default-features = false, optional = false }` but it didn't make any difference. It still lists the same list of 380 errors, all ending with `not found in crate root`. But I can't add it to the root crate because it's a 'virtual' crate. Any ideas? My code is in https://github.com/reinvantveer/rust-mega-drive/tree/main/examples/megatowerdefense if you want to look into the details.

Comment: Ah I can add it to one of the libs, I'll try and report back

Comment: I tried adding it to one of the library crates, but that didn't work out either. Same result: the 380 errors. I'm beginning to think this isn't going to fly.

Comment: Hmm this is really weird, I just tried compiling a static-lib with the rand crate and it worked no problem. This must be very specific to your crate setup

Comment: I just tried compiling the megatowerdefense crate and it compiled just fine. Maybe this is an enviromental problem? What OS are you on? And during the compilation of which crate does it face problems?

Comment: I used the Dockerized setup to build the cross-compiler and the cargo-megadrive command with the examples: `docker build -t rust-m68k:latest -f Dockerfile.toolchain . && docker build -t rust-mega-drive .` from the project root. This will set you back a few hours, but then it errors out at compiling the megatowerdefense crate on the last build step of the `Dockerfile`. This is on Ubuntu 20.04 but that shouldn't matter with Docker. But maybe it's to do with the cargo-megadrive command/extension?

Comment: I checked and a default `cargo build --release` passes, so I'm accepting your answer @Misty! Thanks for all the good pointers, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: One other thing: you need `rand = { version = "0.8.3", features = ["small_rng"], default-features = false }` for it to skip the compilation of features that pull in `libc` as a dependency. Could you update your answer @Misty?

Comment: @Rein sorry for my lack of responses, I didn't have access to my computer lately. I updated the answer. Good you figured it all out :)

Comment: You're totally fine @Misty, thanks for the helpful answers and the time you committed, it's greatly appreciated.